# JavaScript Discord How can the message be detected on a server and on the channel, on a specific channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, channel, discord.js

I want the bot to detect a message from a server and send it to my personal server, in a specific channel. How do I make that code and how do I incorporate it into mine?

MY CODE

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'xdd';

client.login(token); // login the bot with your token.

client.on('message', message => {

        if(message.content.toLowerCase() === 'help')
                message.channel.send("hello " + message.author + "!");
        else if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes('time'))
        {
                var date = new Date();
                message.channel.send('The time is ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds());
        }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `message` event will listen for messages across all guilds, so you can keep that as is. What messages you want to listen for are completely up to you.

Once you've determined what messages you need to send:

You can get the server using the guilds property:

```
  var guild = client.guilds.array().find(ch => ch.name === "Server Name");
```

Then get the channel within that server

```
  var channel = guild.channels.array().find(ch => ch.name === "Channel Name");
```

Then send the message to that channel using the `send` method.

```
channel.send("Hello World!");
```

Hope this helps!

DJS Docs: https://discord.js.org/#/

EDIT: Revised my answer to use `client` instead of `bot`, since I see that is what you are using as the `Client` instance.

Comment: But what I want is that when someone puts "! Order", that message arrives at my server so I can go to serve him

Comment: This example assumes that you have the bot listening across multiple servers. The bot will listen for messages across the guilds it has joined (`client.on('message'`). In your case, when the `message` event is triggered, you'll be looking for the message to contain `! Order`. `if` it does, then send that message to your server using the steps outlined above, where `"Server Name"` in the above code is the server you want to send the message to, and `"Channel Name"` is the channel in your server you want the message to be sent.